# I can't publish my self-answer because my question is closed

Tags: discussion, specific-question, closed-questions, self-answer

I asked [a question about Grocery CRUD](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47334158/show-a-specific-record-id-in-grocery-crud-list) and it was suggested that I edit it for better understanding. The question was then put on hold because it was too broad. I have an answer to the problem, but due to it being on hold I can not publish it.

What should I do, or what else could I change to be admitted again?

Comment: Regardless of whether you now have an answer, the question is off-topic..so it's not required.

Answer (score 11):

The problem is that [this question was initially too broad](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/47334158/1).  Your [later attempts to bring it in-line](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/47334158/2) didn't really appease the PHP crowd who was looking at your question.

In looking at it, despite my aversion to PHP, here's what I'm seeing as the crux of your question:

> I do not know if this is possible, I want, that in my list view of Grocery Crud, only see a specific record, for example, the record with id 5, that way the user can only see that record and not all the records of my table.

You've got an objective and a goal, but you don't specify

- How you're passing this data through to your controller (path param, query param, etc)
- How your DB is wired to this at all (what queries you're using, for instance)

...which is why a passer-by would *rightly* consider it "too broad".

I'm glad you found an answer, but the question itself isn't suitable to be here on Stack Overflow.

Comment: thanks for answer, I still don´t know, maybe at first my question was too broad, but I specified my Framework (Grocery Crud is for codeIgniter) and all the other things that you suggest me the framework do this for itself. So, I do not know what more I can change, maybe I assume that the people know all what I tell you now and that was my mistake.